# sort object array based on string + numeric value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort array using a function. But when the number is going to two digit sorting is not correct. Otherwise it's showing correct result. Please check the code.

this is the function:

```js
var arr = [{name: "a1", value: 1},{name: "a3", value: 1},{name: "a4", value: 1},{name: "a2", value: 1}];

var arr2 = [{name: "a1", value: 1},{name: "a3", value: 1},{name: "a14", value: 1},{name: "a12", value: 1}];

var sort = function (prop, arr) {  
    prop = prop.split('.');
    var len = prop.length;
    
    arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        var i = 0;
        while( i < len ) {
            a = a[prop[i]];
            b = b[prop[i]];
            i++;
        }
        if (a < b) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a > b) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
    return arr;
};
arr = sort('name', arr);
arr2 = sort('name', arr2);
console.log(arr); // it's correct
console.log(arr2); // it's not correct
```

In this case I'm trying to sort the array based on value of `name`.

Comment: Use `.localeCompare` to compare the strings. Although the sort criteria is ambiguous..`a3` could mean both `a03` and `a30` (for comparison purposes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [numeric collation with `String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Numeric_sorting). It will avoid lexicographic sorting and give you proper numeric order:

```js
var a = "10";
var b = "2";

console.log( //false - string "10" does not come after "2" because 1 < 2
  "a > b:", 
   a > b
);
console.log( //-1 - `a` comes before `b`
  "a.localeCompare(b):", 
   a.localeCompare(b)
);
console.log( // 1 - `a` comes after `b`
  "a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true}):",
   a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true})
);
```

Note that this works for *strings*. If you also want to sort numbers, you have two easy options:

- Cast the numbers to strings then use the string sorting with numeric collation. It will work the same and it keeps your code simple.
- Use an `if` to check for what you're comparing and apply the `.localeCompare` logic for strings and a different logic for numbers.

Both would work but I personally prefer the first one, since it doesn't involve maintaining different cases. Thus using it in your solution gives the correct results:

```js
var arr = [{name: "a1", value: 1},{name: "a3", value: 1},{name: "a4", value: 1},{name: "a2", value: 1}];

var arr2 = [{name: "a1", value: 1},{name: "a3", value: 1},{name: "a14", value: 1},{name: "a12", value: 1}];

var arr3 = [{name: "a", value: 3},{name: "a", value: 1},{name: "a", value: 14},{name: "a", value: 12}];

var sort = function (prop, arr) {  
    prop = prop.split('.');
    var len = prop.length;
    
    arr.sort(function (a, b) {var i = 0;
        while( i < len ) {
            a = a[prop[i]];
            b = b[prop[i]];
            i++;
        }
        
        //cast to string
        a = String(a);
        b = String(b);
        
        return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true})
    });
    return arr;
};
arr = sort('name', arr);
arr2 = sort('name', arr2);
console.log(arr); // it's correct
console.log(arr2); // it's correct

arr3 = sort('value', arr3);
console.log(arr3); // it's correct
```

Comment: for the numeric key use `+1`,

Comment: No longer works if sort function will be used for 'value' property

Comment: @Aleksey you're right. I missed that. One easy way around it is to cast both to strings and still rely on collation. The other is to do `if/else` and check what you're actually comparing. I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: Or just simply `a = "" + a` and `b = "" + b` and then it will work for all the cases

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the alphabets and digits and then compare them

```js
var arr = [{name: "a1", value: 1},{name: "a3", value: 1},{name: "a4", value: 1},{name: "a2", value: 1}];

var arr2 = [{name: "a1", value: 1},{name: "a3", value: 1},{name: "a14", value: 1},{name: "a12", value: 1}];

var arr3 = [{name: 1, value: 1},{name: 11, value: 1},{name: 14, value: 1},{name: 12, value: 1}];
var sort = function (prop, arr) {  
    prop = prop.split('.');
    var len = prop.length;
    
    arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        var i = 0;
        while( i < len ) {
            a = a[prop[i]];
            b = b[prop[i]];
            i++;
        }
        let [key1,digit1] = (""+a).split(/(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)/)
        let [key2,digit2] = (""+b).split(/(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)/)
        return (key1 - key2) || (+digit1 - +digit2)
    });
    return arr;
};
arr = sort('name', arr);
arr2 = sort('name', arr2);
arr3 = sort('name', arr3)
console.log(arr); // it's correct
console.log(arr2); // it's not correct
console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: But this no longer works if he will use this function to sort by value

Comment: First array is the same with this method

Comment: @Ali i've fixed the answer you can see the updated one

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid regexp group` in Firefox. The lookbehinds work in Chrome, for now.

Comment: @VLAZ yes there's no support for lookbehind in firefox yet

Answer (score -1):

Name property is of type string that is why sort is performed in lexicographical order(ie alphabetical order). You would need to parse name field to sort by number inside name.